# How to use tags for filtering images to be displayed using views?

Tags: 7, nodes, views

I'm pretty new to Drupal (version 7). I'm trying to create multiple image galleries. I've created a content type called "Images" and use a view to display it like a gallery.

However, I wonder if there is some way to "tag" the images so that they go to different views. Ex.: I have an image tagged so that it will only appear in the "events view" and not the "projects view".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can almost guarantee that this question has been asked before, but still ...

If you did a standard Drupal 7 install, then you should already have a Tags taxonomy. Add that taxonomy to your content type.

In the view, you could do a couple of things.

1. Create more than one variation of the view. In each variation, filter the view to only contain the tag that you want.

OR

2. Use a Contextual Filter to grab the specific term from the URL. That way, you will have as many different views as taxonomy terms. This is more complicated, but it will help you learn a lot, and it is almost always the better way to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just to avoid you're not aware of it yet, know that creating galleries is a common request, which can be solved in various ways ... (no need to reinvent the wheel).

[Talking Drupal #083](http://www.talkingdrupal.com/083) is a great podcast about creating a Gallery, and includes a lot of recommended modules for it.

Just to mention a few of them (mentioned on the linked page):

> - Gallery formatter - https://www.drupal.org/project/galleryformatter
> - Views Slideshow - https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow
> - Flexslider - https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider
> - Node Gallery - https://www.drupal.org/project/node_gallery
> - Multiupload  Filefield Widget - https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_filefield_widget
> - Multiupload Imagefield Widget - https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget
> - Field Focus - www.drupal.org/project/imagefield_focus
> - pl upload - https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload